# cakephp: my domain on shared host justhost is not displaying flash messages

Tags: cakephp, message, shared, host

My domain on the shared host is not displaying any flash messages. It is displaying fine on my local server. I have the following in the students_controller:

```
function add(){

$this->Session->setFlash('Your child\'s admission has been received. We will send you an email shortly.'); 
}
```

I have the following in default.ctp(the layout file) and add.ctp:

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
```

the /app/tmp folder and all the folders within that have the permission 777.

I had also put debug($this->Session->read()); in the students_controller and it is giving:

```
Array
(
    [_Token] => a:5:{s:3:"key";s:40:"39a5e70df521f8f175d20060abb261b69611f0a1";s:7:"expires";i:1327392309;s:18:"allowedControllers";a:0:{}s:14:"allowedActions";a:0:{}s:14:"disabledFields";a:0:{}}
    [Message] => Array
        (

        [flash] => Array
            (
                [message] => Your child's admission has been received. We will send you an email shortly.
                [element] => default
                [params] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

In app_controller.php:

```
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript','Session');
var $components=array('Auth','Session','Cookie');
```

In core.php, I've tried setting:
 Configure::write('debug', 0); instead of Configure::write('debug', 2);
 Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake'); instead of Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');

I have no blank spaces after or before  in routes.php.

Can someone help me out? What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0):

If I try the code abe I get an error that the variable `$session` is undefined. Shouldn't the `check()` call be:

`$this->Session->check()`

I'm not sure you even need the `check()` though, `$this->Session->flash()` won't print anything unless the required Session key is populated.

Comment: Ok, i have removed check(). But it still doesn't work. $this->Session->read() still gives the [message] 'Your child's admission has been received....'. Thats why i don't understand on why $this->Session->flash() is not displaying the message.

Comment: That's rather strange. When I copy paste your code in one of my projects it all works fine. In theory all the stuff you've posted in your question should work now. As your `debug` setting is set to `2` the caching shouldn't matter, but could you empty the `models` and `persistent` directories in `/tmp/cache`?

Comment: i deleted the contents of models and persistent in /tmp/cache. But still no flash message. Data is getting inserted into the database but only no flash message. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, the flash messages are displaying now. The problem was with test.php in webroot. I made the same changes as in index.php to test.php and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive this will help, but here is a link to their knowledgebase:  https://my.fastdomain.com/cgi/help/107

Comment: the link you have given is for flash swf files. My question is abt session flash messages in cakephp.